Visual studio code ctrl + p doesn't search subfolders
I've been using VSCode for years.
I've got a new machine and I've set it up again.
Strangely, when I run ctrl + p to search a file, it only searchs files at the root folder.
It doesn't search files in the subfolders.
If I want to search for files in a specific subfolder, I have to open it in a new vsCode window and run ctrl p there.
Any idea what's going on?

did you set search.exclude?

I didn't touch that
